# UITableView Reload Rows unnaturally jerking the TableView in iOS 11.2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios11, uitableviewrowaction

Strange issue arrived after updating new XCODE 9.2 with iOS 11.2, by calling

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1)
self.tableViewHome.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```

It causes unnecessary jerking the whole TableView, Prior it was very fine with these code.

GIF Image for iOS 11.2

[image]

GIF Image for iOS 11.1

[image]

How to stop this Jerking, I have to reload only one cell in the tableview among two cells.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think its due to iOS 11. In cellForRow you must be adding or removing views from cell view. That is generally the reason for jerks.

Comment: @Mohammad Sadiq: I have added two gif image, one in xcode 9.1 with iOS 11.1 and another is Xcode 9.2 with ios 11.2, same code has been executed in both xcode in different machine. But in 11.2 it jerks but not in 11.1, it is quite strange for me too.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra, any luck with iOS11.2 ? I am facing the same issue. It was not jerking in iOS11.1 but now its showing jerk in 11.2. Let me know if u get any luck.

Comment: @torap I didn’t do any research after fixed that.. what r u getting ? Can u show gif and ur code snippet?

Comment: @AbhishekMitra, checkout this https://giphy.com/gifs/ios11-3ohjV9asyToN6M8tu8

Comment: @torap well i guess ur cell content size is bigger than your cell height size.. look into that thing once and make it sure..

Comment: @torap now I'm facing such situation for ios 11.2, did u get something to stop it in ios 11.2 ?

Comment: @AbhishekMitra, I posted answer below. Please have a look. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For ios 11.2.* **

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension in `viewDidLoad()`

add `estimatedHeightForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.row == 0{

            return firstCellHeight()
        }
        else{

            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
}
```

`firstCellHeight` is my First Cell Height

func firstCellHeight() -> CGFloat{

```
    if UIDevice.Display.typeIsLike == UIDevice.DisplayType.ipad{

        return 400

    }else if UIDevice.Display.typeIsLike == UIDevice.DisplayType.iphone7plus{

        return 230

    }else if UIDevice.Display.typeIsLike == UIDevice.DisplayType.iphoneX{

        return 200

    }else{

        return 180
    }
}
```

and **Don't** use: `reloadRows`

```
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```

Instead use `reloadData` i.e `tableView.reloadData()`

And Finally Where your Action required, Use bellow code:

```
let indexPath0 = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        if !((tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.contains(indexPath0))!) {
            print("Not Visible")

            self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:firstCellHeight() ), animated: false)
        }
```

Comment: use `tableView.reloadData()` after `tableView.setContentOffset`

Comment: Why use reloadData instead of reloadRows, if I need to reload several cells, not whole tableview?

Comment: Thank you helped me. Worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 11):

What I understand is if you really want to use auto sizing cell(and all cell are of different sizes) then above solutions doesn't work for iOS 11.2, So what I tried is as below:

Declare variable to store the height of the cell

```
var cellHeightDictionary: NSMutableDictionary // To overcome the issue of iOS11.2
```

Initialize in viewDidLoad,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 125
    cellHeightDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
}
```

and use like below:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellHeightDictionary.setObject(cell.frame.size.height, forKey: indexPath as NSCopying)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if cellHeightDictionary.object(forKey: indexPath) != nil {
        let height = cellHeightDictionary.object(forKey: indexPath) as! CGFloat
        return height
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

This works for me, Hope this helps to you too

Comment: Thanks Torap for investigating into it. I appreciate your answer by voting up. But I have solved that thing for ios 11.2 in my another answer, you can review it.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I got the answer, I have to use an delegate method of UITableView i.e

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

After putting this method by returning `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` it stop that jerking for iOS 11.2.

Comment: This works for me for 11.1 but not in 11.2. Issue is still present in iOS 11.2

Answer (score 3):

i had same issue. i was doing one thing wrong. 
Automatic Row Height & Automatic Estimate Height in Storyboard were selected and in code heightForRowAt method was also implemented. I un checked Automatic Row Height and only implemented heightForRowAt method. It resolved my issue.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    return 390
}
```

[image]